# Access 2007 - Data provider could not be initialized

Tags: ms-access, vba

I converted Access 2000 app to Access 2007, the App is connect to MsSql-2000 with ADO.
2 Problems:
1. I can not do filter on the form (right click -> filter) - returns nothing.
2. I keep getting "Data provider could not be initialized" mostly when I'm trying to play with the filter

somebody has an idea?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199236-built-filter-functions-failing-when-form-recordsource-set-recordset

Comment: ...you say ADO, but if you're using MDB, you'd likely be using linked ODBC tables, in which case after converting, you should delete all the linked tables and recreate them in the new version because the old metadata stored in the linked table definitions may not be appropriate for A2007.

Comment: Sorry for the late response (Notify Email was wrong) Thanks for your replay-did't Help)-: what I did is:[I'm using MDB]

Comment: strConn= "ODBC;DSN=DSNNAME;Description=MyDESC;DATABASE=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

Comment: For Each tdfLoop In CurrentDb.TableDefs If Not (IsNull(tdfLoop.Connect) Or tdfLoop.Connect = "") Then tdfLoop.Connect = strConn tdfLoop.RefreshLink End If Next tdfLoop

Comment: For Each qdfLoop In CurrentDb.QueryDefs If Not (IsNull(qdfLoop.Connect) Or qdfLoop.Connect = "") Then qdfLoop.Connect = strConn End If Next qdfLoop That is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the error "Data provider could not be initialized" most often occurs because the connection string is not perfect for an ADO connection. The error is not realized until an ADO recordset that uses the faulty connection is created and bound to a form or report.

If working with an Access Project (See: [Create An Access Project](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-an-access-project-HA010167953.aspx)), ensure that the server and initial database (if provided) are verified to be correct in the Data Link Properties. In Access Projects, the connection string is baked into the project itself.

If using a connection string in VBA, ensure that the correct Data Provider is correct. For ADO connections in Access 2003 (MDB and ADP), [the Provider must be Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998), otherwise the recordsets cannot be bound to forms and reports.

Example:

```
' Bind an Access 2003 ADO recordset to an Access form
' Note that the Data Provider is SQL Server (because "Data Provider = SQLOLEDB")

' Declare objects
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn

     .CursorLocation = adUseClient

    ' LockType must be adLockOptimistic
    ' See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic

    .Open "Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;" & _
        "Data Source=ServerName;"
        "Initial Catalog=OptionalDatabaseName;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _
        "Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;"

    Set rs = .Execute("SELECT order_id FROM dbo.Orders")

End With

' This will throw the error "Data provider could not be initialized"
' if the Provider is incorrect
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

Note that an Access project will create the error "Data provider could not be initialized" when the main connection (i.e., Data Link) is incorrect and an attempt was made with VBA to assign a recordset object to a form's recordset. So, the last line of the example would fail if the main connection of the Access project is incorrect. (This is the case even if the connection of the project is completely different from the connection of the recordset object.)

Comment: Your comment about "provider must be OLEDBD 10.0" is only true in MDBs if you're binding an ADO recordset to a form. It's not relevant if you're using regular bound forms with the Recordsource property set to a SQL SELECT.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton  Thanks for the added clarification. I updated the answer to better reflect that it is related directly to ADO.

Answer (score 0):

Also, using Teradata ODBC Connection (Teradata, not Microsoft for Teradata), you can bind to forms using ADO. The data provider not initialized error will come up if you use a datasheet as the form and you attempt to filter on the sheet.